# Power Series Question Relating to ArcTan

Tags: power-series

Why isn't the answer for this 9? If it is different how do I do it? Thanks in advance.!

[image]

Comment: They want the lowest value of ***n*** such that $c_n$ is nonzero.

Comment: [And indeed, it is not $9$.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series%209x%5E2%20arctan(x%5E10)&t=crmtb01)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\displaystyle f(x)=9x^2\left[x^{10}-\frac{x^{30}}{3}+\frac{x^{50}}{5}-\cdots\right]=9x^{12}-3x^{32}+\frac{9}{5}x^{52}-\cdots,$

so $\;9x^{12}$ is the nonzero term of lowest degree.

Comment: The answer was 12 by the way. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know; I guess Omnomnomnom was right about what they were asking for, and he worded the question better.